# How to use multiple different patterns?

Tags: java

how to check strings for multi-pattern regex not for single pattern if tried for one pattern but I need it for multi-pattern and i tried but it doesn't work.
when I running these codes just I can get one of them (time or price ) that is in the String but when I combine them don't show me any output.

thanks for your help....

here is my code :

```
 String line = "This order was  places for QT 30.00$ ! OK? and time is 2:45";
      String pattern = "\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$]"+"\\d:\\d\\d";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );

      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```

Comment: `+` doesn't "combine" patterns; it just performs string concatenation.

Comment: By combine patterns do you mean you want to check for a continuous pattern or check that one of the given patterns is valid.

Comment: You could build an array of Patters and test each of them, but with your example I would just make your regex more adaptable.  Take a look at the Regex `|` (or)

Comment: it should pass even one pattern matches i mean OR not AND

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "+" operator does not separate patterns - it concatenates strings.

What you can do is provide a pattern that accepts characters in between the two groups.

```
  String pattern = "(\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$]).*(\\d:\\d\\d)";
```

The parentheses above are optional. If you include them, you can get the matched price and time as separate strings:

```
 if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) + " with time: " + m.group(2));
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed your comment that you're looking for OR, not AND.

You can do that with an expression of the form `X | Y`:

```
  String pattern = "\\d+[.,]\\d+.[$]|\\d:\\d\\d";
```

This will match either a price or a time, whichever occurs first. You can get the match with `m.group(0)`.

Comment: +1, this is a much more useful approach than a regex to grab a price or a time

Comment: Dear Andy Thomas-Cramer this true but this like AND i should have both of them but I need OR cause may be i don't have time but i have price in the text

Comment: @ToferCriss - See the "Edit" section above for OR. If you prefer AND but will accept OR, then use two patterns -- first try the AND pattern above, and if that doesn't match, try the OR pattern.